# Return LatLng object from nested asynctask

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have spent days on this, but I can't find a solution to my problem:

I'm developing an app that retrieves a list of theaters showing some movie selected by the user, parsing an HTML page in an AsyncTask.

I want to visualize those theaters on a Map with markers, so I need coordinates: once the "GetCinemaList" AsyncTask is completed, I try to populate my markerList in onPostExecute.

I have an SQLite db in which I store [theater|city|lat|lng]. So I first look up in the db, if it is not found I want call another AsyncTask to retrieve coordinates from HTTP google geocoding ('cause device geocoder returns null, causing the app to crash)

The problem is I am not able to return the LatLng point to the first AsyncTask...

I have tried to use listeners and to override processFinish(LatLng p), but I can't assign the value to my variable cause, accessing it from inner class it should be final.

Any help/idea? Thanks!

Here my code (containing error) for the AsyncTasks , in my Activity.

```
private class GetCinemaList extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, List<String>> {
    private Context mContext;


    public GetCinemaList(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        List<String> cinemas = new ArrayList<>();
        Document docHTML = null;
        try {
            docHTML = QueryUtils.makeRequest(urls[0]);
            cinemas = QueryUtils.extractCinemasFromHTML(mTitile, docHTML);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("JSwa", "Problem making request for parsing HTML "+e);
        }

        return cinemas;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        cinemaList = result;
        LatLng point;

        pointList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String elem : cinemaList) {
            String name = elem.split("\t")[0];
            String orari = elem.split("\t")[1];

            Cursor cursor = queryDB(mCinemaDbR, city, name);
            if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                // call geocoding service

                new LatLongFromService(name.concat(" " + city), new AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(LatLng output) {
                        point = output;
                    }
                }).execute();

                Log.d("JSwa", "Inserting point "+point.toString());

                // insert new value in the database
                long id = addCimena(mCinemaDbW, name, city, String.valueOf(point.latitude), String.valueOf(point.longitude));
                // insert new value in the list

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(name).snippet(orari);
                pointList.add(marker);
            }
            else{
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CinemaEntry.COLUMN_LAT)));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CinemaEntry.COLUMN_LNG)));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(name)
                        .snippet(orari);
                pointList.add(marker);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        for (MarkerOptions marker : pointList){
            m_map.addMarker(marker);
        }

    }
}
```

// Sometimes happens that device gives location = null

```
public class LatLongFromService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, StringBuilder> {

    String place;
    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public LatLongFromService(String place, AsyncResponse resp) {
        this.place = place;
        delegate = resp;
    }


    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
            String googleMapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + this.place + "&sensor=false";

            URL url = new URL(googleMapUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream());
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
            return jsonResults;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            JSONArray resultJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

            JSONObject location = resultJsonArray
                    .getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

            String lat_helper = location.getString("lat");
            double lat = Double.valueOf(lat_helper);


            String lng_helper = location.getString("lng");
            double lng = Double.valueOf(lng_helper);

            delegate.processFinish(new LatLng(lat, lng));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: you already have pointList right, take from it?

Comment: @ntaloventi I don't get your comment. pointList is a List<LatLng> declared as a global variable of my Activity. I need to fill it with LatLng object that corresponds to the theaters in cinemaList! 
But I cannot retrieve those latitude and longitude values without my app crashing

Comment: @Fed The results returned by the google maps depends on the address. If you give an invalid address then google maps will give the result as `zero results` in which case you can't access the lat/long like you are expecting to. Have you verified the result of your google call with the address you are actually looking for?

Comment: @Coder yes! I have checked that the address is valid, and the url works.
If I separately run the code of the task for testing, printing on the screen the point, everything works. Also printing and pasting the URL in my bowser, give me the right json.

It is the combining of the two things that is a lot more difficult than expected.

Comment: @Fed any progress in the implementation? I am not a Android expert so I hadn't took a stab at the code.

Comment: @Coder yes, I have basically changed the logic and directly add the marker on the map (also updating my db) in the onPostExecute of the LatLngFromService AsyncTask, getting rid of the AsynResponse. That was the only solution I came up with. 
I'm waiting to have enough reputation to answer my own question :)